# DataTable loses data when called in another form

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have two webform say **wf1** and **wf2**,

I've data in ***wf1 gridview gv1***, Now i'm trying to copy this data to another form like

```
wf2.gv2.DataSource=gv1.DataSource; 
wf2.gv2.DataBind();
```

if I see using breakpoint, I have data in ***gv2*** of ***wf2***, but when i try to view that ***gv2*** in ***wf2***, there is no record in it.
In *wf2* i have added

```
 myDiv.Controls.Add(gv2);
```

Hope you understand my question. Can you tell me why, I'm struck in this issue for 3 days

Answer (score 1):

gv1 is not persistence and loosing its state.

What you need to check is : when page is rendered completely gv1 have lost it values as you are on other web form.
You need to find different approach or try out playing with Page load methods

Comment: Thanks frnd, but i don't know how to do that, as i have just started my career in programming, do you have any example to show how to achieve it by other approach or page load methods. Thanks in advance.